# Python: Как сравнить два списка с условием?

Tags: python, list

Есть два списка

```
a = [401, 604, 547, 700, 722, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700] 
b = [900, 0, 333, 803, 838, 400, 467, 488, 432, 700]
```

Нужно сравнить между собой элементы списков так, чтобы новый список состоял из чисел, которые больше. Т.е.

```
[900, 604, 547, 803, 838, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700].
```

И чтобы отображалась сумма этих элементов т.е. `Сумма: 7148`

Comment: расскажите что вы пытались сделать, что не получилось, выложите ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [401, 604, 547, 700, 722, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700]
b = [900, 0, 333, 803, 838, 400, 467, 488, 432, 700]

c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(max(a[i], b[i]))

print(sum(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [401, 604, 547, 700, 722, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700] 
b = [900, 0, 333, 803, 838, 400, 467, 488, 432, 700]
c = [max(x, y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(c)
[900, 604, 547, 803, 838, 845, 621, 490, 800, 700]
print(sum(c))
7148
```

Comment: можно просто: `sum(map(max, zip(a, b)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = [max(a[i], b[i]) for i in range(len(a))]
list_sum = sum(new_list)
```

P.S. генераторы работают быстрее циклов